# Typescript migrating from JavaScript，build error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

run build error，as
[image]

The tsconfig.json is:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/", // path to output directory
    "sourceMap": true, // allow sourcemap support
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true, // enable strict null checks as a best practice
    "module": "es6", // specify module code generation
    "jsx": "react", // use typescript to transpile jsx to js
    "target": "es5", // specify ECMAScript target version
    "allowJs": true // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
},
"include": ["./src/"]
```

}

webpack.conf.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['awesome-typescript-loader']
        },
        {
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'source-map-loader'
        },
    ]
},
```

package version
"webpack": "^3.12.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
"typescript": "^2.9.2",
"@types/react": "^16.4.11",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7",

I tried to update webpack version but useless

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use webpack 4? That's what your typescript loader is asking for

Comment: I tried install webpack 2，the problem still exists

Comment: Yes, but what about version 4?

Comment: why need update webpack，version4 is not backward compatible，I tried install low version typescript and awesome-typescript-loader is not useless

Comment: Install older `awesome-typescript-loader` to match webpack 3 - 2